# Number column type in oracle to mysql conversion

Tags: mysql, oracle

What is the equivalent of below oracle data types in mysql.

```
column1 number(13,2)


column2 number(null,3)
```

I tried with int and bigint and it's not working and I am getting error.

EDIT--

error : sql not formatted properly.

Comment: If you get an error, share the error message

Comment: number are FLOATS, DOUBLE OR DECIMAL types see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html

Answer (score 2):

You could use decimal

```
 column1 decimal(13,2)
 column2 decimal(3,3)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same database schema across different RDBMS you can use NUMERIC

```
 column1 NUMERIC(13,2)
 column2 NUMERIC(3,3)
```

This is the SQL standard so it works in Oracle and Mysql (and SQL Server/PostGreSQL, too).